# Java Generic Methods in Predicate Interface

Tags: java, generics

This is the code from the Predicate functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Predicate<T> {

    boolean test(T t);

    default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
    }

    static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
        return (null == targetRef)
                ? Objects::isNull
                : object -> targetRef.equals(object);
    }
}
```

Why is the `and` default method NOT using the type parameter `<T>` before return type in the method signature?

I thought `default <T> Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other)` is correct since this is using the return type `Predicate<T>`.

Comment: Because the `T` is already defined by the class declaration. The `T` defined in `isEqual` is specific to that method. Its confusing because they have the same name, but they are different types. [Defining Simple Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/simple.html) shows the first case, [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) shows the second.

Answer (score 0):

Obicere already mentioned it.

`and` returns and accepts a Predicate withe the same generic type as `this`.

```
Predicate<String> isNotNull = s -> s != null;
Predicate<String> andNotEmpty = isNotNull.and(s -> s.length() > 0);
```

While `isEqual` is `static` it does not "inherit" the generic type of its class declaration and defines its own `<T>`. It is more like a factory method for creating a Predicate comparing to a fix object.

```
Predicate<String> isEqualToSth = Predicate.isEqual("sth");
```